# Почему текст не обтекает картинку?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет

Вот пример : [клик](http://codepen.io/Nikulio/pen/NpmXPb)

```
.f_right {
    float: right;
}
.text {
    max-width: 400px;
    width: 100%;
}

<div class="text">
            Смішна, завжди усміхнена та натхненно відповідальна Собака-Продавака була винайдена спеціально для вас і для того, щоб допомогти відшукати на теренахC Фори найвигідніші ціни на покупки. Всі хіти продажу саме на цій сторінці! Акційні товари оновлюються щотижня, і найбільші знижки на них можна і потрібно відстежувати. Слідкуйте за новинами на сайті або у вашому магазині біля дому.       
<img class="f_right" src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="prodavaka" style="
    margin: 10px;
">
        </div>
```

Вроде всё ясно, как день. Но он берёт и не обтекает!
В чем может быть проблема?

Спасибо

Comment: изображение необходимо поставить перед текстом https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/4pd0afwj/

Comment: ставите картинку перед текстом и выставляете `float:left` или `align=left` или `right`

Comment: @soledar10 Спасибо :)

Comment: @L.Vadim Спасибо :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Картинка должна быть в начале абзаца:

```css
p {display: block; width: 100%; float: left}
img {width: 240px; float: left; padding: 0px 10px 4px 0px;}
```

```html
<p>
<img src="http://etherdynamic.ru/uploads/posts/2011-04/1303670236_599.jpg" alt="lasd"/>
Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
</p>
```

```css
p {display: block; width: 100%; float: left}
img {width: 240px; float: right; padding: 0px 0px 4px 10px;}
```

```html
<p>
<img src="http://etherdynamic.ru/uploads/posts/2011-04/1303670236_599.jpg" alt="lasd"/>
Sed ut perspiciatis, unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, quia voluptas sit, aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit, qui in ea voluptate velit esse, quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum, qui dolorem eum fugiat, quo voluptas nulla pariatur? At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus, qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti, quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint, obcaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa, qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio, cumque nihil impedit, quo minus id, quod maxime placeat, facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet, ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat.
</p>
```

Comment: Спасибо!

Помогли